# What is the typical measurement error in EDX peak location?

Tags: measurements, spectroscopy, x-rays

In [EDX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-dispersive_X-ray_spectroscopy), peak locations (kV values) give information about elemental composition of a sample.

How accurate is the position of those peaks? For example, could Pd ($L_{\alpha}$ 2.838 kV) possible show up as Ag ($L_{\alpha}$ 2.984 kV)? And vice versa? What about element pairs with even smaller difference between their characteristic peaks?

Comment: It depends on the accuracy of the calibration.

Comment: @Pieter so how accurate can this get?

Comment: Depends also on resolution and on the number of ADC channels, but something like 1 % of the energy should be possible. So in this case, around 30 eV.

Answer (score 1):

There are various error sources to consider.
First of all, the sample: For L-lines, the chemical shift can be up to a few eV.

Typically, in EDS systems, the peak-position shifts as function of count-rate. How much varies wildly between systems. Temperature variations of both the detector and electronics can also cause misalignment of the energies in the spectrum.

Comment: Do you know roughly the order of magnitude? few eV, tens, hundreds..?

Comment: The 1% by @pieter sounds like a good ballpark figure. If you have access to a machine, at least the count-rate dependence should be easy to check.